# How to extract a dataset from azureml.core.model.Model Class?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Azure Machine Learning Service's Model Artifact has the ability to store references to the Datasets associated with the model. We can use `azureml.core.model.Model.add_dataset_references([('relation-as-a-string', Dataset)])` to add these dataset references.
How do we retrieve a Dataset from the references stored in this Model class by using a reference to the Model Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that a Dataset was added as a reference to a Model with the name `'training_dataset'`

In order to get a reference to this Dataset we use:

```
model = Model(workspace, name)
dataset_id = next(dictionary['id'] for dictionary in model.serialize()['datasets'] if dictionary["name"] == 'training_dataset')
dataset_reference = Dataset.get_by_id(workspace, dataset_id )
```

After this step we can use `dataset_reference` as any other AzureML Dataset Class object.

Answer (score 0):

```
get_by_name(workspace, name, version='latest')
```

**Parameters**

```
workspace
```

The existing AzureML workspace in which the Dataset was registered.

```
name
```

The registration name.

```
version
```

The registration version. Defaults to 'latest'.

```
Returns
```

The registered dataset object.

Comment: The idea is if two Datasets (the names of which we do not know during this step) had been registered with this model during training (say). Then, how do we extract these two datasets? We do not know the name, but we know that they are registered with the model. If we know names, then adding Dataset References to Model Artifacts does not add any value.